# Sentence withても which might not mean "even if"?

Tags: grammar, translation

I have a character that says this phrase, he (A) fights with an enemy (B), where B doesn't put a lot of effort to go against A (he uses magic from a distance to fight.

> A says: 楽しくねえだろう。片手間に遊んでもらってもよお。

A's sentence that I can see has てもらう just sounds very odd to me here and I cannot understand properly...
A is the one receiving the action of getting fun/entertainment, right? I don't quite understand what he is trying to express. Also, his sentence ends with もらってもwhich confuses me a bit, and he also has the ’よお’part which gives me the feeling that he says 'come on/will you'? as if to express his dissatisfaction with this fight, that it's not fun (like he said before).
If anyone can provide with any kind of interpretation I would be grateful.

EDIT: I was thinking if this could be an inversion? I didn't consider it because it wouldn't fit the speech style of the character. Even so, if it would be:

> 片手間に遊んでもらってもよお楽しくねえだろう。

I still don't quite make sense of it. So in this context fighting is 'fun' for A and if A is the one 'receiving the favor of getting entertained' (sometimes I do understand better with very literal explanations), then, can it mean something like " Even though you are playing with me in your spare time, it's not fun, y'know." I really have doubts about my interpretation...

Comment: Just an idea but would it not be better to start reading Japanese using some other material than manga?

Comment: I do read other things, it's just that I found quite a lot of challenging things sometimes in manga because I often find slang terms and such, informal way of speaking that I do not get sometimes, because I was not taught in school that way.

Comment: Ok, I suppose my comment is about the number of manga reading questions on the site in general rather thsn you in particular.

Comment: The sentence as quoted does not appear to have ても anywhere in it.  It has で (not て, and which is part of 遊んで) followed by も (the start of もらって), and it has て (the end of もらって) followed by も, but neither of these are the word ても..

Comment: @Foogod
Hmm, no? But is it not 遊んでもらう＞て-form=遊んでもらって, then followed by も+the よ emphatic particle? well here as よお which I guess the intention was to make it sound longer. So, uhm, what can you tell me,like do you have an interpetration?

Comment: Sorry, I had myself turned around a bit (still learning myself).. I checked a couple of references and realized we are talking about the same thing, just in different ways..

Comment: This kind of dialogue, which is from a medium partly consisting of pictures, and often consists of colloquial expressions, is very difficult to get right, and the questions being asked about it usually seem to be so vague that the people asking the questions don't really know the language in enough detail to really understand what they don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

> 楽しくねえだろう。片手間に遊んでもらってもよお。

You're right that it's an inversion. The normal word order should be:

> 片手間に遊んでもらっても、楽しくねえだろう + よお。

The よお is a lengthened pronunciation of the final particle (終助詞)「よ」.

「てform + もらう」 means "receive an action from someone (for my benefit)" → "have someone do something for me".

So 「(AがBに)遊んでもらう」 would be "A receives the action of playing with A from B" → "A has B play with A"

The 片手間に means "not seriously", "not earnestly", or "casually".

The 遊ぶ indirectly means 戦う.

So the sentence is like...

> *Lit.* "Even if I have you play with me not seriously, I'm not having fun, you see?" /
>   "It's not fun when you fight so un-seriously, you see?"

... implying "Come on, fight seriously!"

Comment: Thank you! I think that what was also hard for me to grasp was the use 片手間に here because I mostly saw definitions that mean 'spare/free time' and I just couldn't understand how it should have been understood. And yeah it made sense after reordering the sentences, it stumped me a little because I  haven't many phrases ending in ても (colloquial speech is not my forte so if this happens in conversations, I wouldn't know so good) instead of being at the start or middle of sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong (I often am), but I think the use of 「もらっても」 here is a common idiomatic construction for asking for a favor:

て-verb + もらっても = "can you let me ..." / "could you do for me ..."

I believe this is a contraction of the full phrase 「もらってもいいですか」 ("Is it ok if I have ...?" (lit, "if you give (it to me), is it good (ok)?"))

So my (admittedly non-expert) reading of

> 遊んでもらってもよお

is something along the lines of "could you please let me have some fun?!"

I'm not sure I really understand the use of 「片手間に」 in this context, though..

Comment: It's not asking for a favour in this case, it is talking about an ongoing action.

Comment: @Foogod
That's what I was thinking, but I never encountered such a contraction and I was wondering if the よお, part could be male speech, to say いい, because logically,after seeing the character end his sentence like that, I thought that it should be てもいい。 Also the 片手間に bit I don't get it either, my feeling was that character A (who says those lines), is somehow mocking character B (like 'in your gracious spare time I received humbly the favor of you entertaining me) something like that (;'∀') I think...

Comment: @Ben
Can you perhaps give me more details? I know that when もらう is used, or in this case verb+てもらう it's usually the meaning of 'had someone do something' (as in you asked them, and you are grateful for the actions) "I got/had someone to do X for me" and I tried to figure out the lines I wrote with these meanings, since A is the speaker, もらう is used so he is the subject of receiving something.